# Android random color for recyclerview textview

Tags: java, android

```
       Random rnd = new Random();
           int currentStrokeColor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));

            movieVH.initial.setBackgroundColor(currentStrokeColor);
```

I am implementing recyclerview with textview and buttons and tried to give random colors for textview but it doesn't appearing

Comment: Please add some reproducible code

Comment: what is movieVH.initial? is it a text view or image view or what? show your xml, a little bit of more code. If it is a text view then instead of setting background color, change text color.

Answer (score 1):

You can import

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import java.util.Random;
```

And then use

```
Random r = new Random();
datePicker.setBackgroundColor(new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255)));
```